# Google (chart) Visualization: showing value in legend

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've added a Google Visualization pie chart to my page. It's all working great and I didn't have a problem customising it with the predefined options. However, there isn't an option to display the values within the legend instead of percentages, only within the slices themselves or on the hover tooltip.

I'd like to show the values in the legend and the percentages in the slices (the latter I can do through options).

For a bonus point... can I append "MW" on the end of the values i.e. 145WM is outputted rather than just 145.

My current chart's code: http://pastebin.com/4JJdpxKx

I'm sure it's obvious but the data is being brought in dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to add the value to the legend is to change the values or formatted values of the label column's data, which will also change the labels in the tooltips.

Appending "MW" to the end of your numbers is easy: just use a [NumberFormatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter):

```
// format column 1 as "1,234 MW"
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,### MW'});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The appending MW worked perfectly, many thanks for that!

Adding in the values to the legend seems out of my reach for now it would seem. In this case, I would actually like to hide the values but keep the names of the slices if that makes sense (in the image below, hide the %ages but keep the country name). Don't seem to have the option for that either :/

Lastly, there's some weird alignment bug... http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8076/36wq.png. You can see it for France's value in the slide. Can't seem to align it properly as the rest do.

Comment: You can't turn off the percentages when using setting the `legend.position` option to `'labelled'` (it's strange, I know).  Alignment issues like the one you see with France are usually due to one of two things: either improper loading of the API, or drawing the chart inside a hidden div.  From the code you put on Pastebin, it doesn't look like either case applies to you.  You are the second person in the past couple of days to report an issue like this.  In the other case, the alignment issue was only present in Chrome, and only for some of the users (I could not replicate it myself). cont...

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list.  Include code that reproduces the problem for you (a link to your Pastebin is fine if that code exhibits the problem) and as much detail about your local environment as you can provide (operating system, browsers used [with version numbers]).

Comment: Hi Asgallant. Again, many, many thanks for the reply. One thing that is interesting about the alignment bug... it's present on the actual Google Visualization pie charts page, see screenshot: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/8324/7ger.png. I can confirm this is present in Chrome under OSX Mountain Lion but not Firefox or Safari for me (would like the know how that works, surely it's tested most in Chrome!). I'll submit a bug report to the link you posted :)

Comment: Bug report submitted: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1364&thanks=1364&ts=1384766979

Comment: I've also marked this as best answer as I think you've given as much info is anyone could!

Answer (score 21):

It's hard to find proper documentation for Google Charts, and my biggest fear is that because it isn't documented it could be taken away any time, but this should do what you want:

```
chart1.options = {
    .
    .
    .
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    legend: {
        position: 'labeled',
        labeledValueText: 'both',
        textStyle: {
            color: 'blue', 
            fontSize: 14
        }
    }
};
```

for both the ***pieSliceText*** and ***labeledValueText*** I have successfully used the options:

```
 value
 both
 none
 percent
```

However, I'm not sure about ***percent*** because I get the same result if I use any junk word. As for ***pieSliceText*** it seems it does not accept the value *both*. Also, *none* is not recognized on the *labeledValueText*.

So, to be sure you'll have to try the different combinations. I personally would have like to have *both* on the *pieSliceText*, but getting it on the labeled legend is good enough for me.

It's unfortunate that Google Charts lack consistency in their options, but that might be because they won't want to continue supporting them. It's even more unfortunate that if documentation for these exist, it is nearly impossible to find.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. I really couldn't find these legend options in zoogle's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create variables and dynamically fetched the data.

```
var legendValue = 100;
var legendText1= 'legend1' + legendValue;

data.addRows([[legendText1,legendValue],[],[]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below setting

```
legend: { position: 'labeled', labeledValueText: 'none'}
```

And code below to customize legend text

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < dataPie.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    total = total + dataPie.getValue(i, 1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataPie.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var label = dataPie.getValue(i, 0);
    var val = dataPie.getValue(i, 1);
    var percentual = Math.round(((val / total) * 100));
    dataPie.setFormattedValue(i, 0, label + ' - ' + ' (' + percentual + '%)');
}
```